# iPhone: How much OpenGL cleanup do I need to do when a context goes away?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures, eaglview

I several views in an iPhone app which happen to use independent openGL contexts. They are not necessarily long-lived so they go away before the process does. And they have a couple textures in each.

Does `-release`ing the `EAGLContext` cause all that GL state to get cleaned up for me? Or am I leaking textures etc by not finding a place to call `glDeleteTextures` from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All resources associated with a sharegroup are destroyed, when the last reference to that sharegroup is released (usually by destroying all of the shared contexts).

Do be careful: when you make a context current for a thread, that counts as a reference.  A context will not be deleted until it is detached from all threads that it may have been bound to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on making the context non-current.